# Writing to FIFO file with c

Tags: c, bash, raspberry-pi, fifo, raspbian

I am relatively new to programming. What I am trying to accomplish is to write to a FIFO file I think its called. Basically if I am at a terminal window I can execute the command `echo "0=0" > /dev/pi-blaster` it will work as intended. So what I want to do is write a program that will basically execute that command for me but change the numbers between the double quotes. I know how to change the numbers with a loop I am just having trouble getting it to actually write the file. There are no errors being generated during compilation or running it simply does not function as if I were to type the command above. Like I said I am new to programming so maybe I am not even on the right path. I have included my code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

   int main(void)
   {
      FILE *fp;
      int i;

      fp = fopen("/dev/pi-blaster", "w");
      if (fp == NULL) {
         printf("I couldn't open pi-blaster for writing.\n");
         exit(0);
      }

      for (i=0; i<=10; ++i)
         fprintf(fp, "echo %d=%d", i, i*i);

      return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Is it possible that it's a buffered write, and you're not seeing it happen because it hasn't been flushed yet?  Try fflush(fp) after the fprintf to force a flush.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what that means

Comment: you should not write `echo`, just write `"%d=%d"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is writing the actual `echo` shell *command* to the file, not e.g. `0=0`.

You should only do

```
fprintf(fp, "%d=%d\n", i, i * i);
```

PS. You don't need to worry about flushing the file buffers, it will be done automatically when the file is closed, and the file will be closed when the process exits (but it's considered good to explicitly close files that you open, even if it's not technically needed).

Comment: do you know if there is a time delay in `C` I would like to wait a second or two before continuing in the script at different intervals.

Comment: @Yamaha32088 There is no native "sleep"  functionality in older C versions. C11 (still considered very new so not all compilers support it) has [`thrd_sleep`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/thrd_sleep). On Windows you have [`Sleep`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and on POSIX platforms (e.g. Linux and OSX) you have [`nanosleep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nanosleep.html).